# "Service user" for Visual studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a system that pushes work items into Visual Studio Team Services. 
Is it possible to add a user that does not have its own email to the project? So I don't have to use my own user for this service?

All I want is to add a user with alternative credentials who is not a actual person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is impossible.

To push work items, you need to use a VSO user account which has the **Edit work items in this node** permission under Area security.

Comment: Thank you for the answer